# How do I get a smaller size of an avatar image

Tags: images, thumbnails, avatar, cropping

I have a function that creates a bio-line at the top of every post. One part gets the avatar of that user, that he uploaded in WordPress (I use a plugin so people don't need to use Gravatar for this).

```
function mm_author_byline()
{
    if (is_single() AND (get_post_type() == 'post' OR get_post_type() == 'theme_product_review')) {
        ?>

        <div class="mm-byline-image">
            <?= get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ?>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
```

The problem now is, that this image is neither cropped, nor is it sized down. It takes the original image, that can be huge. How can I get a sized down version of the avatar image?

Comment: I think nobody knows what plugin did you use for gravatar replacement, how it saves images etc...

Comment: I used ProfilePress (used to be WP User Avatar)

Answer (score 1):

`get_avatar` takes a second parameter according to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) for avatar size. If you're using a plugin that doesn't respect that, you'll need to reach out or check their documentation for a way to change the size.